# SQL JAVA EE WHERE statement isn't taken into account

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, where-clause

I connect to a database with something like 50 tables, referenced in a table inside the database. The problem I'm having, is for one of these table, the WHERE statement in the SQL query is simply not taken into account by the query, like it was inexistent. I tried a lot of thing, like using row index instead of row name to reference it in the query. I searched for a while but nobody seems to have had the same problem.

It's strange because it happens in only one query, all the other work just fine, on the same type of data, same WHERE. So the solution is probably dumb, but at this point I need another point of view.

The second query below works just fine, but it's just as if the WHERE statement wasn't there... But the first one achieve is goal as intended.

```
resultCompare = compareStat.executeQuery("SELECT Nb_doc_Notes, Nb_doc_SQL FROM Comparaison_Replique_Resultats WHERE Table_SQL_associee = '"+tableName+"' ORDER BY ID_Comparatif DESC;");
                resultCompare.next();
                int numberLines = resultCompare.getInt("Nb_doc_Notes");
                numberEntries = resultCompare.getInt("Nb_doc_SQL");
                resultCompare.close();

                resultCompare = compareStat.executeQuery("SELECT ID_Comparatif FROM Comparaison_Replique_Resultats WHERE Difference = "+REQUIRED_DIFFERENCE+" ORDER BY ID_Comparatif DESC;");
                resultCompare.next();
                int ID = resultCompare.getInt("ID_Comparatif");
                resultCompare.close();
```

So when I check the "ID_Comparatif", it just get the last one in the table, ignoring the fact that Difference is almost everytime different from REQUIRED_DIFFERENCE (equals to 0 BTW, it's just that during my preliminary testing I tried putting the value in a variable and then concatenating it, just like in others query I have in the program.

Thanks !

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you have here is wide open to sql injection. You don't want a visit from bobby tables. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is an app used in intern, and none of the data is given by the user, it is retrieved from a trusted database just before this part.

Edit: Plus only trusted users are able to access it, and it's on an intranet.

Comment: I just quick read your code. In the first query, you use `WHERE Table_SQL_associee = '"+tableName+"' ORDER BY...` and in the second `WHERE Difference = "+REQUIRED_DIFFERENCE+" ORDER BY`. Notice the simple quotes not appearing in the second one

Comment: There's more to parameterized queries than SQL injection.  They also help to avoid the very error that hosed this app.

Comment: Do not leave your code open to accidental SQL injection, either, nor to indirect injection in the event that a third party manages to inject code into the trusted database as text.  Do not leave any possibility for data to be misinterpreted as code.  There is no excuse for not using parameterized queries.

Comment: @jhamon I tried with and without single quote, and in the first query the data is a string, whereas in the second it is an int, it's actually the ID field of the table.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to change all of this to use prepared statement and i'll edit my post when it's done.

Comment: For the apparently-failing query, I suggest selecting also the `Difference` column, so as to verify on the Java side whether the `WHERE` predicate is satisfied.  I predict you will find that it is -- in other words, that you're performing a different query than you think you're performing, or that your data are different than you think they are.

Comment: All of your arguments about not fixing the injection vulnerability to not hold any water at all. Today it's on the intranet but what happens next month when the CIO says "I want this online so I can get to it from home"?? It is so simple to parameterize queries. Also, if somebody else looks at this code as an example but they are working on your corporate website....well...

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, you were right and I'm dumb, I forgot another criteria of selection, and thus it didn't gave me what I wanted. Thanks a lot, I indeed needed another point of view and the solution was indeed simple.

Thanks all.

Comment: @Bjornir Please keep a professional language on SO.